# Модальное окно fancybox относительно родителя

Tags: html, jquery, css, fancybox

Привет, не получается реализовать открытие модального окна fancybox в том div, в котором оно собственно и располагается. По дефолту модальное окно fancybox открывается относительно body и располагается по центру всей страницы. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы модальное окно открывалось в пределах родительского див и располагалось относительно его. Заранее благодарю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так может быть вам и не нужен fancybox? Опишите вкратце, что должно получиться на выходе? Возможно то что вы хотите, можно реализовать ajax и css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как например:

```js
$(".modal-trigger").fancybox({
  beforeShow: function(){
    $(".fancybox-overlay").appendTo(".box");    
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  width: 70%;
}

.modal-trigger {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}



.modal {
   display: none; 
}

.box {
  height: 50vh;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.7/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.7/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="wrap">
    <aside>
      
    </aside>
    
    <main>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="#modal" class="modal-trigger">Open Modal</a>
        
        <div id="modal" class="modal">
          <h2>Модальное окно</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: гениально) благодарю